# pySerial - login prompt being written to buffer when writting a message to tty serial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to use a GSM modem on a RPi4 to do a simple TCP connection to a remote server. I have this working, but when I go to write a message to the server, the login prompt for the pi is included in the byte stream sent to the server.

My objective is to have only what my code sends to be sent to the server :)

My relevant python3 code is:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)
ser.write((f'AT+CIPOPEN=0,"TCP","{config.server_host}",{config.server_port}').encode())
ser.write(b'AT+CIPSEND=0,')
time.sleep(5)
ser.write(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n')
ser.write(b'\x1A')
```

And what I receive on the server is:

```
connection from ('x.x.x.x', yyyyy)
received b'\r\n\r\n>garage logi'
received b'n: Password: GET'
received b' / HTTP/1.1\r\r\n'
no more data from ('x.x.x.x', yyyyy)
```

Can someone help me understand where this `received b'\r\n\r\n>garage logi'...` is being injected into the write buffer of the serial connection?

I have tried using `ser.reset_input_buffer()` and `ser.reset_output_buffer()` but no changes. I have increased, removed, etc the sleeps. No changes ever.

Comment: Those AT commands might be sending a reply and that's what you are seeing.

Comment: They do send a reply, the code I posted is much simpler than the real code, but reduced for brevity. But the AT command replies are from the modem itself, usually like "OK". But they never should be trying to gain shell to the system itself. And when I read the serial buffer, I have never seen this in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the serial port had a login shell attached to it by the Raspberry Pi. I disabled this login from `raspi-config` and that resolved the issue.